# How to branch a subbranch as a different dev branch with upcoming commits and merges without instigating a merge conflict cluster****?

Tags: git

So I have this layout...

```
Master
 \
  \
   Dev Branch
        \
         \
        Feature Branch A
```

But moving between projects, I'm about to add a branch with this layout...

```
Master
 \      Feature Branch B
  \     /
   Dev Branch
        \
         \
        Feature Branch A
```

But here's the tricky parts... Feature Branch A has features that will help with Feature Branch B...

```
Master
 \      Feature Branch B (should start with code that's presently in A)
  \     /             ^
   Dev Branch         |
        \             |
         \            |
        Feature Branch A
```

And to top it off, before Branch A or B get merged in, Dev Branch will get other branchs that will be merged in first, that both have to merge in before they resync, meaning B can't stay based off A...

```
Master
 \      Feature Branch B (should start with code that's presently in A)
  \                      /  ^          /     \
   Dev Branch-------------- | ------- / ------------
   \     \    \             |        /       /
    \     \    \            |       /       /
     \     \  Feature Branch A---- / ------/
      \     \                /    /
       \     \              /    /
        \    Feature Branch 3   /
         \                     /
          Feature Branch Number 4
```

So how do I start Branch B to where initial code is based on A, but not tied to it, but instead technically still based on Dev so other stuff can be merged into it later without problem to where it can then remerge into dev later without problem? I mean, I could just branch dev and then copy-paste code from A, but I expect that will resort in absurd merge conflicts later that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Can't you just create your branch `b` and open pull requests from the other branches (first one from branch `A`) when needed?

Comment: I literally don't know if I can. Last time I got close to something close to this complexity, merge conflicts were a nightmare as git thought half the stuff was rewriting text with the same text, and I'm trying to avoid shooting myself in the foot again. Would that work well in this scenario?

Comment: Well, that's what I would do... But there will probably be merge conflicts since your feature branches and destiny branches have different bases...

Comment: So... no real way around weird merge conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only certain features you need from a different feature branch, you can always [cherry pick them](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) into your own feature branch.

Or, if "B" needs all the stuff from "A" anyway, just [rebase it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) on top of "A" and have all the features from "A". Keep rebasing regularly to catch any conflict early-on, before they pile up.

And if you keep source files short and to the point (i.e. no files with thousands of lines of code) you can further reduce the chance of running into complicated conflict situations.

Also, with a good editor or merge tool, its much easier to fix merge conflicts. You get a three-pane view of what is coming from were.

Comment: So if I'm reading that right, do a branch off of dev onto B first and then rebase B on branch A and then begin development on branch B?

Comment: If you begin the development of "B" then you could just branch off of "A", if the required features already exist there. But assuming that "A" and "B" are being developed in parallel, and then "B" gets features "A" needs, you can rebase "A" on top of "B" at that point. Or again, at any point later.